# How to create a text file using a bamboo task

Tags: file, bamboo

I just started on an old project using maven, and I move it to Bamboo for CI. For executing the tests, it needs some local configuration file. For the moment, these files are stored in our git but it is not optimal.
I would like to know if there is a tasks for creating a text file in the local build repository. The content of the text file must be editable in the task configuration panel.

As a workaround, I could use the script task, but it is not really optimal...

Comment: why is it not optimal to use the script task? you can also write a little python script or what ever to create a file... i don't understand the problem

Comment: You can write a plugin for it or find one that is already written. No other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you correctly, you're trying to inject runtime values needed for testing from within the bamboo plan configuration.

If this is what you're trying to do, then why not pass the needed runtime values as [Bamboo variables](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Bamboo+variables) and then just access them as you would any usual environment variable.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Nope, I a file to be created with a content defined in the task configuration. I didn't found any plugin for this so I a currently creating one.

Comment: @Teocali Then just use `bash`? Why create a plugin when you could just echo into a file?

Comment: Because it is more complicated to configure for the user.

Answer (score 0):

I use this createFile.bat:

```
set bat=%2
set output=%1
echo Creating file %output% from %bat%
type %bat%  | find /v "createFile " | find /v "::::" > %output%
```

then in bamboo you add task script:

```
createFile check.ps1 %0
::::
file contents....
```